# Getting runtime error while trying to run Runserver in python Django

Tags: python, django, web, runtime-error

So I have received a code that is not mine. My aim was to run the Django website I received as they told me all was working fine. But when I tried to run Runserver I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\eneko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\eneko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 327, in execute
django.setup()
File "C:\Users\eneko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", 
line 18, in setup
 apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
 File "C:\Users\eneko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
 packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Users\eneko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
 File "C:\Users\eneko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
 File "C:\Users\eneko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
 packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
File "C:\Users\eneko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):

RuntimeError: __class__ not set defining 'AbstractBaseUser' as <class 
'django.contrib.auth.base_user.AbstractBaseUser'>. Was __classcell__ propagated to type.__new__?
```

These are my package versions:

Django          1.9.13
django-autoslug 1.9.7
pip             20.1.1

My python version is 3.8.2

Help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.9 requires Python 2.7, 3.4, or 3.5 as per [official release note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/1.9/)

so try with python version 3.5

Comment: Or, better, if possible upgrade Django to at least 2.2, preferably 3.x ...